# after_filter access rendered template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

Was wondering if anyone knows how to access the rendered template in Rails3 in an after_filter?

I would like to use an after_filter in my ApplicationController and modify the HTML if certain conditions exists using Nokogiri.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was really simple....

```
response.body
```